# Run Youtube video in Floating activity

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to run a youtube player using the API in a floating activity. To aim that, I'm using the library https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut and the youtube API. But I'm always getting the same error whatever I'm trying to do:

> youtubePlayerview can only be created with an activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.

It's because the view is launched in a Service but how can I avoid this problem and run my youtube view in a floating window?

I tried to get the View in the activity which launch the service to reach the youtubeView and initialize it from there, but always the same error.

Comment: by a "floating activity" do you mean dialog?

Comment: No it uses a TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window.

Answer (score 0):

The example which provided in StandOut github page uses extends StandOutWindow such as:

```
...
public class MostBasicWindow extends StandOutWindow {
...
```

And the warning you get says you should extend YouTubeBaseActivity as activity context.
I think there is a conflict between `context` preferences because both of the elements you want to use demands different `extends` as `context`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

> A fragment that contains a YouTubePlayerView. Using this fragment is the preferred way of playing YouTube videos because your activity does not need to extend an activity provided by the library, as is the case with using the YouTubePlayerView directly.

Try using `YouTubePlayerFragment` More info:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment